# Sharing data between node.js and a processing sktech

Tags: node.js, processing

Is it possible to share data between a processing sketch and a node.js server (running on the same machine)?

Comment: can you specify in your post whether you mean stand-alone Processing talking to node.js over a TCP/IP connection, or whether you mean a sketch running on a webpage (applet or through Processing.js)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need some type of IPC (inter-process communication) mechanism to send data between processes.

In the Node.js world there's a popular program named Redis. It implements the [publish/subscribe pattern](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). A process subscribes to a channel (aka, the reader) and another process publishes to that channel (aka, the writer).

In the node.js side you can use the [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#publish--subscribe) client. In the processing sketch side you can use any of [these clients](http://redis.io/clients) depending on the language you're using.